# Mean of the selected row in grouped dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by, apply

can you please help me with the following situation? I want to groupby my df based on team and season and then I want to get mean of the goals scored till the date of the match. I thought about using `rolling`, but I cant figure it out how, since for each row it will different.

DF:

```
Date      Home   Away    Season  Home_goals  Away_goals         
1.1.2019  Team 1 Team 2  2019    1           1
2.1.2019  Team 3 Team 4  2019    2           3
3.1.2019  Team 1 Team 3  2019    2           1  
2.1.2020  Team 1 Team 4  2020    3           4
4.1.2019  Team 1 Team 5  2019    1           3
```

Expected output:

```
Date      Home   Away    Season  Home_goals  Away_goals  Mean_home_goals       
1.1.2019  Team 1 Team 2  2019    1           1           1
2.1.2019  Team 3 Team 4  2019    2           3           2
3.1.2019  Team 1 Team 3  2019    2           1           1.5((1+3)/2)  
2.1.2020  Team 1 Team 4  2020    3           4           3 (its new season)
4.1.2019  Team 1 Team 5  2019    1           3           1.33 ((1+3+1)/3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `Home_goals` at row 3 `2` or `3`?

Answer (score 1):

If you sort by the date, you can then group everything by `Home` and `Season`, and then just calculated an expanding mean on it:

```
In [327]: df.sort_values("Date").groupby(["Home", "Season"])["Home_goals"].expanding().mean()
Out[327]:
Home    Season
Team 1  2019    0    1.000000
                2    1.500000
                4    1.333333
        2020    3    3.000000
Team 3  2019    1    2.000000
Name: Home_goals, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
groups = df.groupby(['Home','Season'])['Home_goals']
df['Mean_home_goalds'] = groups.cumsum()/groups.cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
       Date    Home    Away  Season  Home_goals  Away_goals  Mean_home_goalds
0  1.1.2019  Team 1  Team 2    2019           1           1          1.000000
1  2.1.2019  Team 3  Team 4    2019           2           3          2.000000
2  3.1.2019  Team 1  Team 3    2019           2           1          1.500000
3  2.1.2020  Team 1  Team 4    2020           3           4          3.000000
4  4.1.2019  Team 1  Team 5    2019           1           3          1.333333
```